# Sending data from child window to parent window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a parent popup and a child popup and I want to pass one array to the parent popup using Javascript. I tried everything but it's not working at all. What should I do here?

The code below does nothing. I want to put the value of `ret` into the parent window.

```
var ret = new Array(Number(txtfolioID.value), txtfolioName.value);
var opener = window.opener;
if (opener) {
  opener.setFolio(Number(txtPortfolioID.value), txtPortfolioName.value);
}
```

Parent aspx page

```
window.setFolio = function (folioID, folioName) {
  document.getElementById("txtPortfolio").value = folioName;
};
```

**Console Error**

> firebug-lite.js:11885 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

**EDIT**
I changed the code completely and now I am checking that element exists in DOM or not.

```
      var folio = window.parent.document.getElementsByName("txtPortfolio");
      folio.value = 'somevalues';
```

but I am not able to assign the value the textbox.please help

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors in the parent after trying to call `opener.setfolio()`? Is the content of both the parent and child popup on the same domain?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I checked console there is no error but few lines are there. opener.setfolio() is written in child popup. Also how to check parent and child popup is in same domain?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is no error I checked in console but setfolio function is not called